# How to get correctly difference new generated unique ids and full list of all ids?

Tags: php, arrays, compare, uuid

I have sample function for generate unique ids:

```
function generate_uuid($needed_ids_num = 1, int $random_bytes_length = 6)
{
    $ids = [];
    while (count($ids) < $needed_ids_num) {
      $id = bin2hex(random_bytes($random_bytes_length));

      if (!isset($ids[$id])) $ids[$id] = true;
    }
    $ids = array_keys($ids);
    return $ids;
}
```

I have this unique ids on database:

```
$ids_from_database = array(
    'ad5dcc895ddc',
    '3d036129b5b4',
    'db569298c1ea',
    'f919a34b31db'
);
```

How can I generate a unique identifier by comparing already existing identifiers from the database?

My rewrited variant function is sample:

```
function generate_uuid(array $ids_from_database, int $needed_new_ids = 1, int $random_bytes_length = 6)
{
    $temp = $ids;
    $needed_ids_num = count($ids) + $needed_ids;
    while (count($ids) < $needed_ids_num) {
      $id = bin2hex(random_bytes($random_bytes_length));

      if (!isset($ids[$id])) $ids[$id] = true;
    }
    $ids = array_keys($ids);
    $result = array_diff($ids, $temp);
    return [
        'new_uuid' => $result,
        'ids' => $ids
    ];
}
```

Why my wrote function not return result arrays in incorrect variant?

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your problem, I think your first function was OK, just need to pass the ids that you got from db in this case `$ids_from_database`. Just compute the difference between array with `array_diff()` and pass the result with unique  ids and all db ids. Hope this help.

```
<?php
function generate_uuid(array $ids_from_database, int $needed_ids_num = 1, int $random_bytes_length = 6)
{
    $temp = $ids_from_database;
    $ids = [];
    while (count($ids) < $needed_ids_num) {
        $id = bin2hex(random_bytes($random_bytes_length));
        if (!isset($ids[$id])) $ids[$id] = true;
    }
    $result = array_diff($ids, $temp);
    return [
        'new_uuid' => $result,
        'ids' => $temp
    ];
}
$ids_from_database = array(
    'ad5dcc895ddc',
    '3d036129b5b4',
    'db569298c1ea',
    'f919a34b31db'
);
$generated_ids = generate_uuid($ids_from_database);
print '<pre>';
print_r($generated_ids);
print '</pre>';
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://eval.in/1029502

Comment: On your thinks this function accurately generate a unique identifier comparing already existing in a database return result? How can I check the function for accuracy comparison? Why new identifiers are not written to the final result array `$result['ids']` ? @Being Sunny